# Combined <input type='text'> and <select>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-select, react-select

My web application requires a text input box that can act as a result for a `<select>` as well. The design that we have is the following

[image]

When the user types in the `<input>` box, a dropdown with a single option "Go to blah..." should show (where blah is the content of the input).

When the user presses the down arrow to the right, a list of options should show. Selecting one of those options should replace the content of the editable input with the chosen option.

Any pointers of what is the best way to achieve this? I can implement my own, but that sounds like quite a commitment. Ideally, I want to tap into some existing library (either fully or partially) and convince only the down arrow to open a dropdown of the same size of the input, while the `<input>` is controlled by me.

The example in the image is generated with `react-select`, but I was not able to convince the library to behave the way I described.

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve something similar you can use `input list` with `datalist`.

> The HTML `<datalist>` element contains a set of `<option>` elements
>   that represent the permissible or recommended options available to
>   choose from within other controls. ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist))

Example:

```html
<label for="url2go2">Go to:</label>
<input list="urls" id="url2go2" name="url2go2" placeholder="/" />
<datalist id="urls">
    <option value="/url1">
    <option value="/url2">
    <option value="/url3">
    <option value="/url4">
    <option value="/url5">
</datalist>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is really close to what I was thinking of, with the exception that on selecting the input, the dropdown should not be shown. Only the arrow at the right should display the dropdown upon press.

Comment: I found something nice on google but it use jQuery http://projects.sergiodinislopes.pt/flexdatalist/